# What does " message.Incoming" mean?

Tags: case

My colleague's code has this statement:

`if(c.Status=='closed' && message.incoming)`

What does message.incoming actually mean?

Comment: Seeing more code, especially where the message variable is declared or populated would help us answer you.

Comment: `message.incoming` doesn't mean much to anyone else without seeing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`message` is an object of some (unknown) type and `incoming` is a boolean field on this object.

Your colleague could have written `if(c.Status=='closed' && message.incoming == true)`, which would have been clearer.

An `if` statement expects a single boolean argument so the `&&` construct performs a logical `and` operation on the two arguments ( so multiple parameters can be combined together )

ie, the outcomes of this statement are:

```
c.Status=='closed' and messaging.incoming == true  --> true
c.Status=='open'   and messaging.incoming == true  --> false
c.Status=='closed' and messaging.incoming == false  --> false
c.Status=='open' and messaging.incoming == false  --> false
```

Hopefully this illustrates how an `if` statement works.

If you just wanted to know about the email message object, [here is a reference](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)

Here is the part you wanted to know:

- Type - boolean
- Properties - Create, Defaulted on create, Filter
- Description - Indicates whether the email was received (true) or sent
  (false).

Answer (score 0):

Here **message.incoming** will return **TRUE** or **FALSE**, Because incoming field of message object is Boolean. so we can directly use like

```
if(message.incoming){
//**Code Block**
}
```

if the value of **incoming** field is **TRUE** then only it will execute the **Code Block**,So instead of **message.incoming==True** your colleague used **message.incoming**.